# multiple ssl certificates on single heroku app?

Tags: heroku

I have an existing multi-tenant heroku app that uses wildcard subdomains to route requests currently serving the following types of requests below over https/ssl using a wildcard ssl certificate

https://app1.example.com
https://app2.example.com

Is it possible to add another seperate single domain ssl certificate to serve requests on a url like:

https://app3.custom-domain.com

Assume all requests are being handled by a single dyno

Answer (score 8):

It's possible and not difficult to do.

Just add the domain to Heroku:

```
heroku domains:add app3.custom-domain.com
```

As for the certificate, get a [multi domain SAN certificate](http://www.ssl.com/certificates/buy) and include all the domains in the SAN field; your wildcard `*.example.com` and also the separate domain `app3.custom-domain.com`.

Please note you will still be charged wildcard rates for the wildcard domain in the SAN field. I know because I've done this.

Comment: This is a great route. See my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/36474485/630614 for more details.