# Mutiple domains with SSL endpoints on one app on Heroku

Tags: heroku

The company that I work for is partnering with another organization and they want to white-label our Django app (which is hosted on Heroku).  We currently have an EV certificate and SSL endpoint.  The new goal is to secure both domains and avoid any certificate nags/warnings each time a user goes to the page via the new domain name.

I believe that I should be able to accomplish this with a SAN/UCC certificate.  I've found a couple of very similar question posted.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448012/multiple-ssl-certificates-in-one-heroku-application).  However, while the page referenced in the previous answer still exists, the anchor for "serving-multiple-domains" is no longer on the page.  And doing a search on the page doesn't find anything (maybe I'm missing it).

My question is does Heroku still support this functionality?  If so, is a SAN/UCC cert the best way to accomplish this?  Are there other options?