# Can I use an EV SSL and a Wildcard SSL on the same domain, on Heroku?

Tags: security, ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate, devops

Here's what I would like to setup:

```
EV -> https://example.com/*
EV -> https://www.example.com/*

non-EV -> https://client1.example.com/*
non-EV -> https://client2.example.com/*
non-EV -> https://client3.example.com/*
...
non-EV -> https://client999.example.com/*
```

If I buy one EV SSL, and one Wildcard SSL, is it possible to do use them like I just described on Heroku?

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely possible to install different SSL certificates for the same hostname. For that, you need to have multiple SSL endpoints routing traffic to your domain.

For further information, you can refer this discussion - [Multiple SSL Certificates in One Heroku Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448012/multiple-ssl-certificates-in-one-heroku-application/36474485)

Comment: While the link may help to answer the question, links tend to go dead over time. Please summarize the main contents of the link in your answer using the edit button, so that others may benefit down the line.

Answer (score 0):

[Wildcards cannot be used with EV certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate):

> Wildcards are banned, preventing EV holders from using domain names
>   similar to other companies and thus preventing phishing.

Therefore in order to represent

```
EV -> https://example.com/*
EV -> https://www.example.com/*
```

you would need two separate EVs, one for `example.com` and one for `www.example.com`. An alternative would be to have a non-EV certificate on one of the domains, which then redirects to the other, EV one. Because it redirects, the user's browser would not even see the EV status of the first certificate. Also, as per the comments from the OP, a [multi-domain cert](https://www.digicert.com/ev-multi-domain-ssl.htm) would of course suffice.

The non-EV domains can be covered by a single wildcard cert.

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448012/multiple-ssl-certificates-in-one-heroku-application/36474485) linked to in [Jaymin Dangi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39702853/413180) should show you how to achieve this.

Comment: They have multi-domain EV SSL certificates now. https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo/ev-multi-domain.aspx

Comment: Of course, for some reason I was thinking you wanted a wildcard for your EV cert and it didn't occur to me to have multiple domains instead. Thanks, answer now updated.