# No-op dyno on Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, certificate

I have the exact same situation described here: [Multiple SSL Certificates in One Heroku Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448012/multiple-ssl-certificates-in-one-heroku-application), which is I want to securely access the same application using different domains.

The technique described in the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18982770/1981720) is promising, however I just discovered Heroku started a free service called Automated Certificate Management, which automatically takes care of creating and renewing certificates, which is great. But this is only available for applications with paid dynos.

I don't mind paying 7 $/month for a Hobby dyno, however as my app will only be used for SSL traffic, I don't know how to start a dyno without anything to run. In other words, I want to create a vacant dyno which won't do anything, just to activate the Automated Certificate Management. Is this possible and are there any thing that can go wrong in my plan?

Answer (score 0):

This method won't work with Heroku's ACM, as the domains for which the certificate is generated are the ones the app points to.
So you won't be able to have the certificate on one app, and the domain on another.

However, ACM does handle multiple domains (up to 100), and will generate a single certificate valid for all of them. So while you will have only one certificate, it will work for all of your app domains.